# how to implement own error function while using neuralnet package in R?

Tags: r, function, neural-network, implementation

I am trying to implement a customized error function in package neuralnet in R.

Normally ’sse’ and ’ce’ which stand for the sum of squared errors and the cross-entropy are used to calculate error.Can anyone provide me details about how to implement own error function. Though the package says we can use customized error function,there is no help in the user Manuel about this.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Problem. This is the solution/help I received.
You can use the usual definition of R functions (function(x,y){...}). Hence, the error function must be of the type function(x,y) where x is the fitted value and y is the true value.

Please refer to the following example.

```
library(neuralnet)

AND <- c(rep(0,7),1)
OR <- c(0,rep(1,7))
binary.data <- data.frame(expand.grid(c(0,1), c(0,1), c(0,1)), AND, OR)
set.seed(3)
print(net <- neuralnet(AND+OR~Var1+Var2+Var3,  binary.data, hidden=0, rep=10, err.fct="sse", linear.output=FALSE))

#Call: neuralnet(formula = AND + OR ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3, data = binary.data,     hidden = 0, rep = 10, err.fct = "sse", linear.output = FALSE)
#
#10 repetitions were calculated.
#
#Error Reached Threshold Steps
#7  0.04043122185    0.008248439644   116
#5  0.04426319054    0.009619409680   124
#8  0.04698485282    0.007947430014   117
#2  0.04931335384    0.008792873261    88
#1  0.04965332555    0.009631079320    89
#4  0.05396400022    0.009092193542    96
#6  0.05488395412    0.009990028287   124
#3  0.06383087672    0.009964206587    94
#10 0.51657348285    0.008602371325    51
#9  0.52514202592    0.007890927099    40


set.seed(3)
custom <- function(x,y){1/2*(y-x)^2}
print(net <- neuralnet(AND+OR~Var1+Var2+Var3,  binary.data, hidden=0, rep=10, linear.output=FALSE, err.fct=custom))

#Call: neuralnet(formula = AND + OR ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3, data = binary.data,     hidden = 0, rep = 10, err.fct = custom, linear.output = FALSE)
#
#10 repetitions were calculated.
#
#Error Reached Threshold Steps
#7  0.04043122185    0.008248439644   116
#5  0.04426319054    0.009619409680   124
#8  0.04698485282    0.007947430014   117
#2  0.04931335384    0.008792873261    88
#1  0.04965332555    0.009631079320    89
#4  0.05396400022    0.009092193542    96
#6  0.05488395412    0.009990028287   124
#3  0.06383087672    0.009964206587    94
#10 0.51657348285    0.008602371325    51
#9  0.52514202592    0.007890927099    40
```

You can use basically every error function that can be differentiated.

Comment: Good point. However when writing the cross-entropy as sum (...), R complains that cannot be differentiated. How to solve this?

Comment: @FilippoMazza: Looking at the source code it seems that you don't need the sum() function because this is wrapped around the err.fct automatically. cross-entropy would be err.fct <- function(x, y) {
                  -(y * log(x) + (1 - y) * log(1 - x))
                }

Comment: when I try to run the second: `neuralnet` command, I get the following error: `Error in calculate.gradients(weights = weights, length.weights = length.weights, dims [product 16] do not match the length of object [32]`. Here is my `sessionInfo`: https://i.ibb.co/r6hvvTm/image.png