# Own error function including weights for neuralnet in R

Tags: r, neural-network

My question is very related to this one: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510960/how-to-implement-own-error-function-while-using-neuralnet-package-in-r#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510960/how-to-implement-own-error-function-while-using-neuralnet-package-in-r#_=_) asking for the general syntax for providing a custom error function in the neuralnet package in R.

While the question and its answer is helpful for me already as I also want to use a custom error function. However, in my error function I would like to include the *weights* of every iteration. E.g. I would like to add `lamda*(weights)^2` where my choice of a constant `lambda` influences the optimization's selection of larger/smaller weights. Any idea on how to realize that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pretty sure this is impossible with the current `neuralnet` code.  You can look at it [here](https://github.com/cran/neuralnet/blob/master/R/neuralnet.r).

The relevant section starts at about line 350

```
result <- rprop(weights = weights, threshold = threshold, 
    response = response, covariate = covariate, learningrate.limit = learningrate.limit, 
    learningrate.factor = learningrate.factor, stepmax = stepmax, 
    lifesign = lifesign, lifesign.step = lifesign.step, act.fct = act.fct, 
    act.deriv.fct = act.deriv.fct, err.fct = err.fct, err.deriv.fct = err.deriv.fct, 
    algorithm = algorithm, linear.output = linear.output, 
    exclude = exclude, learningrate.bp = learningrate.bp)
startweights <- weights
weights <- result$weights
step <- result$step
reached.threshold <- result$reached.threshold
net.result <- result$net.result
error <- sum(err.fct(net.result, response))
if (is.na(error) & type(err.fct) == "ce") 
    if (all(net.result <= 1, net.result >= 0)) 
        error <- sum(err.fct(net.result, response), na.rm = T)
```

Here you can see that the internal `err.fct` is explicitly passed only the `result` of the network and not the weights.  If you wanted to pass the weights and a lambda parameter you would need to change the source code.  Although perhaps not for the 'faint of heart' this is indeed possible as you can always download the source and begin modifying it.

Comment: thanks! that helps! as I'm one of the many coursera machine learning kids I guess I'll rather translate my octave code to R for building my own functions that I then fully understand and have full control over rather than messing with this package.. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give this a go. So I downloaded neuralnet.r and edited it:

1. Changed line 364 from line `error <- err.fct(net.result, response)` to `error <- caseweights %*% err.fct(net.result, response)`.
2. Changed line 367 from line `error <- sum(err.fct(net.result, response), na.rm = T)` to `error <- caseweights %*% sum(err.fct(net.result, response), na.rm = T)`.
3. Changed line 554 from line `err.deriv <- err.deriv.fct(result$net.result, response)` to `err.deriv <- caseweights * err.deriv.fct(result$net.result, response)`.
4. Changed line 588 from line `err.deriv <- err.deriv.fct(result$net.result, response)` to `err.deriv <- caseweights * err.deriv.fct(result$net.result, response)`.

I also added `caseweights` to appropriate function arguments, also to neuralnet, and renamed some of the functions so I wouldn't accidentally be using the standard library ones.

Not sure if this works, though. A simple test seems to work but a more complicated one has trouble converging - it's difficult to set caseweights so that they are not too small or too big.